# Custom validator doesn't work (completely) when annotated by composed constraint @NotBlank

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have a custom validator like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@NotBlank(message = "{state.NotBlank}") // Err...it doesn't work
@Constraint(validatedBy = { State.Validator.class })
public @interface State {
  String message() default "{state.invalid}";

  Class<?>[] groups() default { };

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

  @Component
  final class Validator implements ConstraintValidator<State, String> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(final State constraintAnnotation) { }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
      // return true or false based on some rules
    }
  }
}
```

But there is not way I can make it work annotating `State` with `@NotBlank` — since the later doesn't have the `ElementType.TYPE` in `@Target`), but annotating the fields themselves with `@NotBlank`.

The reason I would like to have it in `State` is because I have to repeat the same constraint to several fields, so if `State` could be annotated with `@NotBlank` would be perfect.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant. You will need to define a new annotation because @NotBlank has the following targets:

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
```

AS you can see you can not apply it to your full interface.

Comment: Yeah, I know it doesn't have `ElementType.TYPE`, but I was wondering if there was a work-around for that...

Comment: What do you expect it to check? All fields?

Comment: No, just the ones annotated with `@State`. I was able to change this requirement, but I don't think there is a way to do this in any case, so your answer is valid.